# Log In with PayPal button JavaScript code builder validation error

Tags: javascript, paypal

Sorry for the basic questions but as a very first step I'm just trying to test the "Log In with PayPal button JavaScript code builder".

I've created an app, gone to this button builder, set the return URL to my localhost and then as that failed to a public website (http://bbc.com) making the same settings on my app details page but whatever I do when clicking the button I get the following error:

"Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request."

I've tried setting the button up for sandbox and production but both fail.

Has anyone had the same issue?  I'm guessing I'm doing something really stupid.  I'm just taking the "Dynamically generated JavaScript" code and adding it to an empty webpage.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use `localhost` as a return URL.

Comment: I was wondering that, that's why I tried a public URL, bbc.com but it still doesn't work.  It doesn't look like that return URL has to do anything so I'm surprised if it actually even matters if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it takes a while (a few hours) for the PayPal API to update to changes in the admin console.  Changes were reflected after several hours, very unhelpful for testing.  That was using the production option.  Even when return_uri was being recognised as correct the scope settings were invalid despite selecting all the correct options.